# Peewee difference between select().limit(1) and get()

Tags: select, get, limit, peewee

whats the difference between Peewee's select with a limit(1) and get AFAIK they they both perform the same query but get raises an exception when it doesn't find a result to the query, which is better to use and why? is there any difference in a performance point of view, a logical point of view or a coding standard that i might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

Not a whole lot, really. The `.get()` API allows you to retrieve a single record efficiently, raising an exception if the record is not found. If instead you call `.select().limit(1)`, you still need to either index into the result set, or advance the results iterator to grab the obj.

Basically, `.get()` is a short-hand for select limit 1, then grab the row (if exists), raising special exception type if no match is found.